# How to automatically move a document from one library to another, based on a column selection in MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007

I work for a medical insurer who receives hundreds of faxes a day requesting Prior Authorizations. The current process we have in place has faxes received digitally by our fax server, then dropped into a SharePoint document library as tiff files. One of our departments goes through the faxes and fills in columns based on info contained in the tiff file, then selects a classification from a dropdown list and saves the properties. This removes the file from the Inbound Fax view and makes it available in a view setup for that classification. Problem is MOSS 2007 libraries are not designed to handle the volume of files we have (and nothing gets deleted so it continues to grow).

We want to setup individual lists for each of the classifications, and have the file automatically transferred to the corresponding document library. Ideally, we would want the column data to be transferred with it. This would be a short term fix while we look into a more permanent solution and upgrade of SharePoint. But at the least, performance would improve as the libraries would contain more manageable volume than the single library we have now.

Is there a way OOB to do this? Or an inexpensive solution anyone knows of? I'm fairly new to SP development, but I can often adapt similar solutions to fit my needs.